# Google Cloud Load Balancing with custom port

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cloud

How to make GCP load balancer work on a custom port, according to [google docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/tcp-ssl/tcp-proxy)

the only supported ports for TCP load balancer are 25, 43, 110, 143, 195, 443, 465, 587, 700, 993, 995, 1883, 5222
and I need other port, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This port limitation is for the TCP proxy load balancer and is due to the way TCP proxy load balancers are managed within the GCP internal infrastructure. It is not possible to use any port outside of this list.

There is still the possibility to ask for a feature request to Google Cloud Platform support so that another widely used port be added to the available ports list.
This is explained in this [online documentation](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).

For example, there is actually [a public feature request to add port 22](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77944636). No ETA is provided for the moment.

Depending on your need, there are various types of load balancers in Google Cloud Platform.

TCP internal load balancer permits selecting any port, but has other limitations.
Depending on your needs, there is certainly a load balancer that can manage your case study.
[Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/) is the page where they are all presented.

Finally this [link](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/about-capacity-optimization-with-global-lb#how_https_load_balancing_works) contains an enormous amount of information about global load balancing and the way it works internally.

Answer (score 1):

The TCP proxy load balancer is limited by the ports it supports as you and @Django said.

However, depending on your use case the network load balancer might suit your needs.
As stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/):

> You can use it to load balance UDP traffic, and **TCP** and SSL traffic **on
>   ports that are not supported by the** SSL proxy and **TCP proxy load
>   balancers**.

The main difference is the following:

Network load balancer:

- Regional
- Non-proxied

TCP proxy load balancer:

- Global
- Proxied